# Embedded "IF" formula breaks occasionally, VBA alternative?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a very large embedded IF formula that appears to occasionally break for no reason. Opening and closing the page a few times eventually gets it working again. I am wondering if there is a VBA alternative for it. Here is the IF formula I am running.

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("76210",E125)),"_012_00762_10",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("76220",E125)),"_012_00762_20",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("76900",E125)),"_012_00769_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("76901",E125)),"_012_00769_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("85702",E125)),"_012_00857_02",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("85710",E125)),"_012_00857_10",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("100800",E125)),"_012_01008_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("100900",E125)),"_012_01009_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("123100",E125)),"_012_01231_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("124600",E125)),"_012_01246_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("124601",E125)),"_012_01246_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("124640",E125)),"_012_01246_40",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("124641",E125)),"_012_01246_41",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("142301",E125)),"_012_01423_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("158801",E125)),"_012_01588_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("158900",E125)),"_012_01589_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159203",E125)),"_012_01592_03",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159303",E125)),"_012_01593_03",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159401",E125)),"_012_01594_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159410",E125)),"_012_01594_10",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159420",E125)),"_012_01594_20",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("159501",E125)),"_012_01595_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("169000",E125)),"_012_01690_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("186900",E125)),"_012_01869_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("213200",E125)),"_012_02132_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("213300",E125)),"_012_02133_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("215400",E125)),"_012_02154_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("220100",E125)),"_012_02201_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("223800",E125)),"_012_02238_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225600",E125)),"_012_02256_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("230700",E125)),"_012_02307_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("230701",E125)),"_012_02307_01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("231800",E125)),"_012_02318_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("235000",E125)),"_012_02350_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("235020",E125)),"_012_02350_20",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("242000",E125)),"_012_02420_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("246400",E125)),"_012_02464_00",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("292900",E125)),"_012_02929_00",""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Basically it is built so a serial number is scanned and it populates a cell for the users who use this sheet with its results from the search. I am already running one macro in this sheet as well. Here is that...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Range("A2:A500, J2:J500"), Target) ' define range of interest
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then ' check it's not "nothing"
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = rng.Count Then 'check for all of its cells being not empty
            On Error GoTo safe_exit 'add error control
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'don't do anything until you know something has to be done
            rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Date 'write Date next to all relevant changed cells
        End If
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Maybe there is a better way to build this search using a formula that isn't using embedded IF statements, but i couldn't think of another way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else have you tried - it looks like you could maybe just use a helper column with vlookup instead?

Comment: refer to my comment belowe. vlookup was giving me issues as it is needing a set input, where mine changes all the time. so vlookup would work, if it was able to search within the input to find the string of numbers to correspond with in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,IF(ISERR(SEARCH($A$5:$A$42,$E$125)),0,1),0)),"",INDEX($B$5:$B$42,MATCH(1,IF(ISERR(SEARCH($A$5:$A$42,$E$125)),0,1),0)))
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER).

Here $A$5:$A$42 contains 76210, 76220, ... , 292900 (entered as text, not numbers); and $B$5:$B$42 contains _012_00762_10, _012_00762_20, ... , _012_02929_00.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have to go more than 2 deep on an `IF` you may want to rethink the usage.

What you can do is build a table from your values. Then reference that table as part of your lookup. Assuming your list of value is in range `D8:E45` you could use the formula `=VLOOKUP(E125,$D$8:$E$45,2)`.

The beginning of your table would look like what's seen below. The input result cell is referencing your input value and pulling the match of the second column.

### [image: Example Table with formula]

To get your table you can take your source formula and replace (Find and Replace - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) some characters with unique delimiting characters. Then use Text To Columns <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and delimit and Copy>Paste special>Transpose to quickly have it close to the format you need.

Comment: Almost the answer. Need to put in FALSE for the Range_lookup parameter. Also, need to somehow get an empty string out when no match.

Comment: For this example: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E125,$D$8:$E$45,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: ok, the problem that i ran into with vlookup is, the input needs to be exactly the same. my IF statements were searching inside of the serial number to find a chain of numbers to determine its part number. This part number is then used to cross reference i drop down list for the user to find what they are looking for. Is there a way to combine the vlookup function with the search function? basically the input is much longer and contains the part number im looking for, i.e. 15880114344110123. the 158801 would be the part number which becomes _012_01588_01.